# Data not rendering after OnCLick

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I am trying to display the data after hitting the "Show the data" button. I can see the data in the console but it is not being display on the page. Could anyone help me out and guide me to let me know what is my mistake. Been struggling for days now. Below is my code. I have edited critical information in the code for obvious security reasons. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

axios.post is used to post the token and
axios.get is used to fetch the data from the backend and display it.

---

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../App.css'

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  
  username: "xyz",
  password: "xyz"
});

const type_no = '88'; 

const URL = `example url://abc.com/abc/${type_no}`;




function getToken(){
  const promise = axios.post("example url://abc.com/", raw)
  const id = promise.then((response) => response.data.IdToken)
  return id
 };

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({data: []});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [err, setErr] = useState('');




   const handleClick = async () => {
    getToken().then(token => {

        setIsLoading(true);
        
          const config = {
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          };
          const {data} = axios.get(URL, config)
            .then((response) => {
              console.log(response);
              setData(response.data);
             
             
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
            setIsLoading(false)
      

        
    })

    
  

  };
  

  

  

  

  console.log('Data: ', JSON.stringify(data,null,4));   

  

  return (
    <div className="form">
      {err && <h2>{err}</h2>}

      <button onClick={handleClick}>Show the data</button>

      {isLoading && <h2>Loading data...</h2>}  

      {data.data?.map(data => {
        return (
          
          <div key={data.id}>
            <h2>{data.email}</h2>
            <h2>{data.first_name}</h2>
            <h2>{data.last_name}</h2>
            <br />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );

  
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you give an example how the `response.data` object looks?

Comment: This may need some debugging, please provide a working example, you can use code snippet of stackoverflow, or any live editor like codesandbox, Also if you don't want to expose the API URL, you can use any fake API instead.

Comment: This is how my response looks in the console-
Data:  [
    {
        "email": "ghj.com",
        "first_name": "ghj",
        "last_name": "jkl",
    }
]

Comment: @Mina, My code works when I use an API url which does not require any credentials, for eg, id token. When I remove "getToken().then(token => {" and "const config" and use a fake url with no authentication required, my data is rendered. But when I add my credential parameters, data is rendered only in the console and not on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've initialized the state data with `{ data: [] }` but after fetching the data you're directly setting the state.
Use `setData({data: response.data})` instead of `setData(response.data)`

```js
import {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../App.css'

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  username: "xyz",
  password: "xyz"
});

const type_no = '88'; 

const URL = `example url://abc.com/abc/${type_no}`;

function getToken(){
  const promise = axios.post("example url://abc.com/", raw)
  const id = promise.then((response) => response.data.IdToken)
  return id
 };

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({data: []});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [err, setErr] = useState('');

  const handleClick = async () => {
    getToken().then(token => {
        setIsLoading(true);
          const config = {
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          };
          const {data} = axios.get(URL, config)
            .then((response) => {
              console.log(response);
              setData({data: response.data});
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
            setIsLoading(false)
    })
  };

  console.log('Data: ', JSON.stringify(data,null,4));   

  return (
    <div className="form">
      {err && <h2>{err}</h2>}

      <button onClick={handleClick}>Show the data</button>

      {isLoading && <h2>Loading data...</h2>}  

      {data.data?.map(data => {
        return (
          
          <div key={data.id}>
            <h2>{data.email}</h2>
            <h2>{data.first_name}</h2>
            <h2>{data.last_name}</h2>
            <br />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I now realised where I went wrong. You saved plenty of my hours!! :)